# Connection to Access database on linux failed unixODBC

Tags: php, linux, ms-access, odbc

Currently I have a website running on a Windows machine at a hostingprovider. On that Windows machine I have a connection to a mdb database using the following code:

```
new PDO("odbc:DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb); DBQ=$this->dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

This is all working fine.

Now I would like to do the same, but then on a linux machine at another hostingprovider (which is cheaper). I only have FTP access to the webserver. I can't install anything on the webserver.

Offcourse the linux machine does not have the Microsof Acces Driver, but it has unixODBC installed.

I can't create a dsn so I think I need a dsn-less connection.

Can unixODBC be used to connect to an Access database?

How should I create a connection to the mdb database on a linux webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have unixODBC installed but you still need a Microsoft Access ODBC Driver and one does not come with unixODBC. There are only 2 I know of for Linux and both would need installing (however, that is still possible with FTP). The 2 I know are [MDB tools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/) which is free and [the Easysoft MS Access ODBC Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html) which you need to purchase. I've never had much luck with MDB tools (various ODBC functions did not work and I don't think it is maintained). I know the Easysoft driver works as I've used it.

Comment: My hostingprovider gives the 'solution' to use ADOdb, but if I look in the documentation of ADOdb is says msaccess is Windows Only. So I was wondering if you could help me to determine who is right?